# Error: [$injector:unpr] on tring to get resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state with resolve:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('emails.list', {
            url: "/list/:folder/:page",
            parent: 'emails',
            templateUrl: "views/emails.list.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Mail Inbox' },
            resolve: {
                searchResult: ['Emails', function (Emails) {
                    return 1;
                }]
            }
        });
}
```

And I have a controller for this state:

```
function EmailListCtrl($scope, searchResult, $stateParams, $state) {
...
}
angular.module('peachy').controller('EmailListCtrl', EmailListCtrl);
```

When I try to pass `searchResult` to controller I get an error [$injector:unpr]. How it can be fixed? (Or may be something wrong in configuration)
Angular version is 1.3.6

**My mistake:**

I called EmailListCtrl using ng-controller. Right way is setting controller name in state:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('emails.list', {
            ...
            controller: 'EmailListCtrl'
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fdShyCiEafWluUR2Mt7m). Try to be sure that even EmailListCtrl recives all the needed dependencies properly:

```
function EmailListCtrl($scope, result, $stateParams, $state) {
  $scope.data = { searchResult : result };
};
EmailListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','searchResult','$stateParams','$state'];
```

the **`$inject`** contains clear definition for angluar IoC ... so I could even use **result** as param name instead of ***searchResult***

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fdShyCiEafWluUR2Mt7m)